# Python changing " \ " to " \\ " in file path

Tags: python

I am trying to access an excel file on my desktop via openpyxl.
I am creating the filename for `load_workbook` like this:

```
import os

folderpath = r'C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop'
add = 'Expense-Tracking ' + str(year) + '.xlsx'     # year is 2019
filename = os.path.join(folderpath, add)
```

Then, when I try to use `filename` to load the workbook I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\Desktop\\Expense-Tracking 2019.xlsx'

Why are the single slashes being changed to double slashes and what can I do to avoid it?

The string I would expect is:

> 'C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\Expense-Tracking 2019.xlsx'

Comment: They *aren't*. That's how escape sequences look like. The problem is clear - that file doesn't exist. If you try to try to use that file name with eg `Win+R` you'll get the same error

Comment: You're just looking at the `repr` of the string, in which slashes must be escaped, since a `repr`esentation is supposed to be a valid literal.

Comment: the traceback prints `repr(filename)` (as opposed to `str(filename)`)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Python prints an exception, such as `FileNotFoundError`, it shows the result of calling `repr()` on the exception. This function tries to represent strings in a way that could be directly entered in source code, so it escapes the backslashes in the path string. Your original string doesn't have escapes because it's a raw string literal (`r"..."`), but that's not how `repr()` formats strings.

Make absolutely sure that the file exists with that specific name.